# asus e200ha - black screen after reset

Tags: windows-10, asus-laptop, reset

I have a laptop ASUS E200HA Vivobook that I originally got with windows 7, and upgraded a few months ago to windows 10.

I tried to reset the computer and delete everything from it. I first chose the option of a normal reset (removing all files and accounts, which was indicated as not taking too much time). The reset process started and got stuck at 58%, and after a while I received a blue screen stating that there was a problem with reset. I tried 3 times.

Then I decided to try the second option (the one that takes several hours). After selecting this option, I have a black screen with 2 options to press f8 or f12. I think, as far as I can remember, I pressed f8 (the order of events may have been reversed, previously stuck at 40% then the black screen appeared). I let the computer work and went to sleep.

When I got up I saw the computer trying to boot, the ASUS logo followed by a black screen. I tried to somehow get into Windows but without success. I also tried the option of forcing the computer to shut down after the logo appeared 3 times as indicated in the ASUS documentation.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to solve the problem without a technician?

Answer (score 0):

Reset is problematic after an upgrade, and I think that your only solution now
is to reinstall Windows 10 from scratch.

You will need a second computer running Windows 10 to prepare the boot media
and download drivers for devices not detected by Windows
(especially if the network card is one of them).

There are many tutorials on how to reinstall Windows 10 from scratch.
A particularly detailed one can be found in
[How to clean install Windows 10 and create boot media: Refresh your Windows 10 PC](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/software/operating-systems/1401617/how-to-clean-install-windows-10-and-create-boot-media).

You will also need to download and install the Asus drivers, found on the page
[ASUS Vivobook E200HA Driver & Tool](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-Vivobook-E200HA/HelpDesk_Download/).

While running the Windows installation, you might consider reformatting the disk
(quick format) in order to clean up unwanted remnants of the botched
installations.

As you have upgraded already to Windows 10 on this computer,
Microsoft supposedly has kept record of your entitlement to run it on your
hardware, so you will not need a serial number to install.

I hope you have kept backups for your data. If not, you need to salvage it
first before installation.
Let us know if you need help in that.

Comment: i've made a USB for re-installation of windows, I've plugged in the device to the computer and turned it on , but still i'm stuck in the same loop, how can i get to the installation menu?

Comment: Ensure the correct order of boot devices in the BIOS.